# Swift Call popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover after presentedViewController?.dismiss

Tags: ios, swift

I am created a method to dismiss my presented view controller, the presented view controller does get dismiss but popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover is not being called, how do I get it to call popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover after dismissing the presented view controller?

```
func dismissPresentedViewController() {
        self.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        popoverPresentationController?.delegate?.popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover?(popoverPresentationController!)

    }

func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {
        print("Here")
    }
```

popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover is not being called, yes I have UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate

```
let popupController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CommentsView") as! CommentsController

popupController.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
popupController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 400)
if let popoverController = popupController.popoverPresentationController {
    popoverController.sourceView = (cell)
    popoverController.sourceRect = (cell?.bounds)!
    popoverController.permittedArrowDirections = .up
    popoverController.delegate = self
}


present(popupController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipopoverpresentationcontrollerdelegate/1622322-popoverpresentationcontrollerdid?language=objc)…

> `popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_:)`
>
> The popover presentation controller calls this method after dismissing
>   the popover to let you know that it is no longer onscreen. The
>   presentation controller calls this method only in response to user
>   actions. **It does not call this method if you dismiss the popover
>   programmatically.**